# Investigate "Bad System Call" on shutil calls with Python3.6 on Solaris

Tags: python-3.x, solaris, shutil

We moved from Python3.3 to Python3.6 on our Solaris environment and I now get this error on our  Solaris setups:

```
$uname -a                                                                                                                                                                                                                                            
SunOS ... 5.10 Generic_118833-33 sun4u sparc SUNW,A70
$mkdir -p test/a/b                                                                                                                                                                                                                                   
$echo "test " >> test/a/b/toto                                                                                                                                                                                                                       
$python3.6                                                                                                                                                                                                                                              
Python 3.6.3 (default, Oct 29 2019, 18:43:57) 
[GCC 4.9.4 20151030 (for GNAT Pro 7.4.2 20160527)] on sunos5
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import shutil
>>> shutil.copytree("test", "gabuzo")
Bad System Call                                                # The interpreter exits !!!
$echo $?                                                                                                                                                                                                                                             
140
$tree meuh/                                                                                                                                                                                                                                          
meuh/
`-- a
    `-- b
        `-- toto

2 directories, 1 file
```

The interpreter exits (after copying obviously correctly the tree) and I can't find a way to dig into this problem (maybe with a traceback of the shutil call)

Comment: Have you tried using `truss` to see what system call it's making, with what arguments?

Comment: Thanks for the idea, I didn't know about this command! I've been able to investigate this further thanks to the stack and to generate a MWE in C to show my admins the libc was doomed :)

Comment: FYI, they are trying to install Python 3.6 on Solaris 10, which does not seem to be that straightforward.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On some of the systems (I'm not admin on), coredumps are configured and this `Bad System Call` generates one which I can `pstack` `pmap`. This was sufficient to investigate the problem further (together with the source code of shutil) and to find what system call did generate this `Bad System Call`. I could finally write a MWE in C that reproduces the problem to show a problem in the installation of the libc on these setups.